# USB data on Pi Zero not working after extending the USB data lines on it to another board

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, usb-device

So, for my project, I took a Raspberry Pi Zero, which is to be put in an enclosure. When placed in the enclosure, the micro USB connectors on the Pi Zero cannot be accessed. Hence I took the USB data lines D+ & D- from the PP22 and PP23 pads on the back side of the Pi Zero, soldered wires to these pads and terminated them on the Pads on a custom made PCB. From these pads, through PCB tracks the USB lines go to a vertical micro USB connector.

Now, when I connect the vertical micro USB connector on the custom PCB to the PC, through a USB cable, I am able to SSH into the Pi Zero.

But, when I connect the micro USB connector on the Pi Zero to the PC, through a USB cable, I am unable to SSH into the Pi Zero, which means the USB is not working in this way.

Please help me debug & resolve the issue.

**Added:**

1. [image: Photo of the micro USB data connector on the Pi Zero, at which the USB is not working.]
2. [image: Photo of the micro USB data connectors on the main PCB, at which the USB is working]
3. [image: Layout photo of the main PCB showing the routing of USB data lines]
4. [image: USB D+ & D- pads on the bottom side of Pi zero, at which wires are soldered and brought to the pads on the main PCB. From these pads, USB signals are routed through differential signal tracks on the main PCB up to the micro USB data connectors.]

Comment: Raghavan K - Welcome :-) Please [Edit] your question and add some clear photos of all the wiring, PCB and connectors that you are describing. (If you are using a PC, you can hit Ctrl+G in the edit box, to get a guided entry process for each photo.) You seem to be describing one configuration which works, and one which doesn't work. Please make it clear which photos show working and which show *non*-working configurations. Please also include the results of any research you have done so far, about the requirements for USB wiring, so that we don't tell you what you already know. Thanks.

Comment: Are the ground connections connected to the connector?

Comment: @Gil Yes, the ground connection is made common

Comment: I thought they show up as serial ports when using the USB connection, how are you able to use SSH on that?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say you can’t access the Pi Zero via SSH? Normaly you would access SSH via a network connection, not via a direct USB connection. Do you realize that only one micro USB port on the Pi Zero allows data and the other is only for providing power? Please show a schematic.

Comment: I'm not really sure i follow but if i understand correctly i would guess that the "stubs" you have added to the USB lines are long enough to disturb the USB signals. That's why it works when you connect the USB at the end of the lines but once you connect the USB to the connector closest the stubs will distort the signal, rendering it useless. Care should be taken when playing with these.

Read more about this issue here: https://resources.altium.com/p/stubs-transmission-lines-what-do-they-do-and-how-do-you-keep-them-happening

Comment: @SamGibson I added the photos of the portions of the PCB, showing the connectors.  Working and non-working connectors are indicated. Layout snapshot is also added. Hope it is useful to understand the issue in a better way. I haven't done much study about USB wiring.

Comment: @pgibbons Pi zero can be configured to work as a USB ethernet gadget. That way, u can SSH into it using a USB connection.  U may read more about it here https://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/

Comment: @StarCat U may see this please https://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/ . Yes, I am aware that only one micro USB connector on the Pi zero has a data connection. The pads on the bottom side of it are tapped and extended on to the main PCB. U may see the attached photos to my original post

Comment: @mnhjansson Yes, seems like what u wrote there may be right. Please see the attached photos to my original post to get a better idea about my problem.

Comment: @RaghavanK thanks! i was not aware of that :)